# JS Anonymous Scope

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

```
this
Application.EventManager.on('Click', function(args) { // event listener, args is JSON
    TestAction.getContents(args.node.id, function(result, e) { 
        console.log(result);
        this.add({
            title: args.node.id,
            html: result
        }).show();
    });
});
```

I'm really struggling with scope and anonymous functions... I want `this` (on the 1st line) to be the same object as `this` (on the 5th line)... `.call()` and `.apply()` seemed to be the right sort of idea but I don't want to trigger the event... just change it's scope....

For a bit of contexts... the `this` in question is a TabContainer and `TestAction` is a RPC that returns content...

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a variable defined on the outside scope that is set to `this`:

```
var that = this;
Application.EventManager.on('Click', function(args) { // event listener, args is JSON
    TestAction.getContents(args.node.id, function(result, e) { 
        console.log(result);
        that.add({
            title: args.node.id,
            html: result
        }).show();
    });
});
```

Thanks to closures, you can do this (err, that), even inside of a function.

Comment: See @bmoeskau answer below for a more beautiful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, @Joey's answer does work in terms of generic JS code.  However, since you are using Ext JS according to your tags, I will point out that the *proper* approach is to call the event callback function within the proper scope to begin with since Ext handles passing and setting scope for you.  E.g., the Ext way would be (assuming your Application class is using the standard Ext `on()` function):

```
Application.EventManager.on('Click', function(args) { // event listener, args is JSON
    TestAction.getContents(args.node.id, function(result, e) { 
        console.log(result);
        this.add({
            title: args.node.id,
            html: result
        }).show();
    });
}, this); // 3rd arg to .on() is scope!
```

Comment: I think you'll have to add `this` to the scope of the inner method call to `TestAction.getContents` (which seems to be an ExtDirect call) too.